# solving equation find real number of x and y

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

how can i solve for x and y that satisfy the equations and find the sum of x and y

$xy^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}}y=20 $

$x^{\frac{3}{2}} + y^{\frac{3}{2}}=65$

suppose $x^\frac{1}{2}$=t
$y^\frac{1}{2}$=s

$t^2s+ts^2=20$

$t^3+s^3=65$

$(t+s)(t^2-ts+s^2)=65$

$ts(t+s)=20$

$(t+s)=20/ts$

is this right way to solve the problem?

im stuck at this point

Comment: Yes, it is perfect way. Just go on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by taking resultants the equations in $s$ and $t$ have the solutions
$$
(t,s)=(1,4),(4,1),
$$
and $s=4t, t^2+t+1=0$
or $t=4s, s^2+s+1=0$. Therefore the real solutions are given by $x=1$, $y=16$ and $x=16,y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$65=t^3+s^3=(t+s)(t^2-ts+s^2)=(t+s)[(t+s)^2-3ts]\\=(t+s)^3-3ts(t+s)\\
=(t+s)^3-3(20)$$
Thus $$(t+s)^3=125$$
or $$t+s=5\quad\text{or} \quad s=5-t$$ thus from $$ts=4$$
we have $$t(5-t)=4\implies t^2-5t+4=0\\
\implies (t-1)(t-4)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a simplier approach

$x*\sqrt(y)+y*\sqrt(x) = 20$

$\sqrt(x^3)+\sqrt(y^3) = 65$

Say $x = m^2$ and $y = w^2$

$m^2*w+w^2*m = 20$

$m^3+w^3 = 65$

$m*w*(m+w) = 20$

$(m+w)^3 -3*m*w(m+w) = 65$

$(m+w)^3 -3*20 = 65$

$(m+w)^3 = 125$

Therefore $m+w = \sqrt[3](125) = 5$

Remember $m*w*(m+w) = 20$

Therefore $m*w = 20/5 = 4$

$m = \sqrt(x)$ and $w = \sqrt(y)$

$\sqrt(x)+\sqrt(y) = 5$

Square both sides

$x+2*\sqrt(x*y)+y = 5^2$

$x+y = 5^2-2*4 = 25-8 = 17$

Answer (score 0):

$$65+3\cdot20=(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^3,$$ which gives
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=5$$ and from the first equation we obtain:
$$\sqrt{xy}=4.$$
Id est, $$(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y})\in\{(1,4),(4,1)\}$$ and we got the answer:
$$\{(16,1),(1,16)\}$$